# \KOMAExecuteOptions creates a problem when I compile it?

Tags: koma-script

Dear all I want to use the following template for proposal we need to write:

[Thesis sources](https://github.com/ppletscher/phd-thesis-sample)

When I compile it I get the following error wich I can't resolve

```
Package scrbase Error: unknown option `fontsize=11pt'. \KOMAExecuteOptions{fontsize=11pt}
```

Do you have an idea what I need to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use broken templates!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `fontsize=11pt` to the option list and remove the `\KOMAExecuteOptions{fontsize=11pt}`

```
\documentclass[%
%    a5paper,
    a4paper,
    fontsize=11pt,
    footinclude=true,
    headinclude=true,
]{scrbook}
```

Alternatively, you may change

```
\KOMAExecuteOptions={fontsize=11pt}
```

to

```
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=11pt}
```